# Custom Navigation Bar in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9

I found this pattern on pttrns.com. How can I make the Navigation Bar line curvy like this in Swift?

[image: Pattern image]

Comment: You can make it by setting navigation bar translucent. Then in your view controller you can add view (it could be image view, view with shaped layer, etc.) to the top.

Comment: I am looking same like design...  is possible to share some sort of code?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a blank `navigationBar` and use the background of the `ViewController` to create this effect. For example, create the image with this curvy on the top and set the image as ViewController. Create an `UIView` that cover the entire `ViewController` and in you class set

```
 var mainScreenSize : CGSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size // Getting main screen size of iPhone

@IBOutlet weak var viewBG: UIView!
let imageObbj:UIImage! =   self.imageResize(UIImage(named: "YourImage")!, sizeChange: CGSizeMake(mainScreenSize.width, mainScreenSize.height))
self.viewBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

EDIT:

Use this function to set the image size to screen size. I change my code above as well.

```
 func imageResize (imageObj:UIImage, sizeChange:CGSize)-> UIImage{

        let hasAlpha = false
        let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sizeChange, !hasAlpha, scale)
        imageObj.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: sizeChange))

        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        return scaledImage
    }
```

Comment: what about the dimensions of the image?

Comment: I edited my answer with a function to change the size of the image to the size os screen. You need to create a image that fit to the aspect ratio of an iPhone or iPad. In my project I am using 1080x1920 and fits well

Comment: Ok so I make a vector image with a curvy path and then I add this image as subview of the Navbar, right?

Comment: No, you set you NavBar transparent or the color that you want and create a vector image with a curvy path and use it as the UIView background. Imagine that you have a blank NavBar and the top of the background of your view is blank as well, so you will get the illusion the is the NavBar is different but is just the union of the NavBar with the top of you background image

Answer (score -1):

You can't. You have to create your own custom view controller that behaves like a navigation bar for that example.

Comment: can you do an example to better understand?

Comment: You could have just commented this. This is not an answer that is constructive towards the goal of the question. Also, there ARE ways through which such navigation bar can be achieved. You should research before posting such answers.